# Assembler,переставить числа

Tags: ассемблер

Задача состоит в том ,чтобы переставить числа в обратном порядке,дан массив байт.Запускаю через dos ,в программе нет ошибок ,но она работает не так ,то есть числа не переставляются.Посмотрите может где ошибка.

```
data segment
  kols db 10
  mass db 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
data ebds

code segment 
assume cs:code,ds:code
org 100h
start:
  push cs
  pop ds ; меняем местами
  mov si,offset mass ; запоминаем адрес начала массива с числами
  mov bh,0
  mov bl,cols
  add bx,si
  sub bx,i
go:
  mov al,[si]
  mov ah,[bx]
  mov [si],ah
  mov[bx],al
  add si,1
  sub bx,1
  cmp si,bx
  jl go
  mov ah,4ch
  mov ah,31h
  mov al,0
  int 21,h
code ends
end start
```

Comment: @Настена Антипова, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Исправил форматирование, но в коде есть явные косяки: `data ebds`, `sub bx,i`, `int 21,h`. В таком виде как есть программа не скомпилируется.

Answer (score 1):

Например (чуть укоротил первый вариант):

```
.model tiny
.code
org 100h

start:
    mov di,offset numbers
    mov si,di
    add si,nlength
go:
    mov al,[si]
    mov ah,[di]
    mov [si],ah
    dec si
    stosb
    cmp di,si
    jl go
    ret

numbers db 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
nlength equ $-numbers-1

end start
```

Answer (score 0):

> в программе нет ошибок

```
mov bl,cols

sub bx,i
```

Это что?
По данному коду претензий нет:

```
go:
mov al,[si]
  mov ah,[bx]
  mov [si],ah
  mov [bx],al
  add si,1
  sub bx,1
  cmp si,bx
  jl go
```

Регистр bx куда указывает?

Comment: Вам вряд ли ответят: вопрос задан около 2 лет назад. Вопрос был поднят в списке "Духом сообщества", как не имеющий ответов с ненулевым количеством голосов. Я поправил форматирование, синтаксис исправлять не стал, хотя там явные косяки (`data ebds`, `int 21,h`).